# Pytorch equivalent of Numpy's logical_and and kin?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Does Pytorch have an equivalent of Numpy's element-wise [logical operators](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html#logical-operations) (`logical_and`, `logical_or`, `logical_not`, and `logical_xor`)? Calling the Numpy functions on Pytorch tensors seems to work well enough when using the CPU, even producing a Pytorch tensor as output. I mainly ask because I assume this would not work so well if the pytorch calculation were running in the GPU.

I've looked through [Pytorch's documentation index](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/genindex.html) at all functions containing the string "and" and none seem relevant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***Update:*** With Pytorch 1.2, PyTorch introduced `torch.bool` datatype, which can be used using [`torch.BoolTensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch-tensor):

```
>>> a = torch.BoolTensor([False, True, True, False])  # or pass [0, 1, 1, 0]
>>> b = torch.BoolTensor([True, True, False, False])

>>> a & b  # logical and
tensor([False,  True, False, False])
```

---

PyTorch supports logical operations on [`ByteTensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/tensors.html#torch-tensor). You can use logical operations using `&`, `|`, `^`, `~` operators as follows:

```
>>> a = torch.ByteTensor([0, 1, 1, 0])
>>> b = torch.ByteTensor([1, 1, 0, 0])

>>> a & b  # logical and
tensor([0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=torch.uint8)

>>> a | b  # logical or
tensor([1, 1, 1, 0], dtype=torch.uint8)

>>> a ^ b  # logical xor
tensor([1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=torch.uint8)

>>> ~a  # logical not
tensor([1, 0, 0, 1], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

Comment: Interesting. I find the conflation of bitwise and logical operators distasteful, but it's effective for my use case (e.g. `(x > 0)&(x < 1.5)`). It might not work in every case, though.

Answer (score 3):

logic and:

```
a * b
```

logic or:

```
a + b
```

Comment: Nice, but missing logical not. The bitwise operators are probably the official way to go now that they've introduced boolean tensors.